# Get Value from Hidden Field jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, webforms, hidden-field

Struck with a simple issue of hidden field like this:

```
      <input id="hid" type="hidden" name="hid" runat="server"/>
```

trying to retrieve like this

```
      var rid = $("#hid").val();
      alert(rid);
```

But still am getting undefined value in the alert. Browser used : chrome

Comment: did you check if the server didn't change id='hid' to something like: <input name="ctl00$hid" id="ctl00_hid" /> ? Press F12 in Chrome to inspect the element.

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the value of the field to begin with?

Comment: From what you have posted, you don't have any value for this hidden field.. And for me chrome just alerts empty alert box.

Comment: Am setting the value on Page_Load as hid.Value="someval"

Comment: Hi Roger,Thanks for your hint it is wrapping hidden feild into  ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hid.

Comment: @Samuel Glad your question got answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working for me. Here is the JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/P5r9N/

**HTML**

```
<input id="hid" type="hidden" name="hid" runat="server" value="working"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
var rid = $("#hid").val(); 
alert(rid);
```

Comment: Am setting the value on Page_Load as hid.Value="someval"

Comment: Can you provide me this info? Open developer tools in Chrome (press F12). Copy the html of your hidden element and paste it here in this post?

Comment: Yes thanks for the hint... it is wrapping the hidden feild as  ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hid... any reasons?

Comment: @Samuel        Asp.Net will automatically wrap your control ids. There are many posts about how to deal with this behavior

Comment: @Pavan This is the behaviour of WebForms, not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem then realized I didn't have the `id` attribute of the hidden field set. After I added the field `id`, this worked fine

```
alert($('#fieldid').val());
```

Comment: Gah! I did the same thing! Haha only I forgot the name attribute, wouldn't have thought of that without seeing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this it will work

```
// By `ID`
alert($('input#hid').val());

// By `Name`
alert($('input[name=hid]').val());

// By `Type`
alert($('input[type=hidden]').val());
```

Answer (score 2):

user978064 is correct. However, this is an alternative solution. 
I had this same issue and somewhat the HTML hidden control does show empty value. I know this is weird!

```
<input type="hidden" id="hid101" value="c5956aeb-96f3-4073-b130-62c8c7fbaca2">
```

`jQuery("#hid101").val();` - This returns empty value

```
<input type="text" style="visibility:hidden" id="txt101" value="c5956aeb-96f3-4073-b130-62c8c7fbaca2">
```

`jQuery("#txt101").val();` - This returns expected value "c5956aeb-96f3-4073-b130-62c8c7fbaca2"

This may help to someone!

Answer (score 0):

Declare `style="display:hidden"` on the `input type="text"`.

The same thing happen to me just now.

Comment: Nor sure exactly how this helps the OP

Answer (score 0):

This post was very helpful to me.  For others who it also helps use type="text" style="display:none;" instead of